# How can I generate text based on a form?

Tags: forms, text

I hope I'm putting this in the right place. I'm trying to figure out how to use a simple script to generate a block of text based on information in a form. Specifically, something like this example:

> Brand: `brand`
>   
>   Name: `name`
>   
>   Amount: `amount`
>   
>   Shipping Cost: $`ship`
>   
>   Dimensions: `size`

To generate something like this:

> **"**`name`**"**
>   
>   **Set of** `amount` **by** `brand`
>   
>   This item is brand new in its original unopened packaging. It measures approximately `size`.
>   
>   Shipping for this item is $`ship`, though I will combine shipping for multiple items. I only accept PayPal, and I do not ship internationally.

Is there any simple(ish) way to do this? I'm a bit of a noob at things like this (I used to do basic html, which may or may not help here). I can't even think of what this would be called, much less how to do it.

If you can answer, please be as specific as possible, because, like I said before, noob. I'll be doing this on Ubuntu if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Forms pass data to a place that you specify, using one of two methods: "GET" or "POST". In any case, wherever you told your form to submit that data will be able to access it, either via PHP, or from the URL. Then you can use that data to "fill in the blanks" for the example you posted above.

I know I didn't answer your question specifically, but I think it would behoove you to read up a little more in order to get a more cohesive understanding of how forms work.

Here is a simple read that will give you a fundamental understanding of how forms work: [reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/My_first_HTML_form).